# How much does robot framework help in terms of employablity?

Tags: automated-testing, robotframework, open-source

I have been learning Robot Framework with python. The basic idea is to make myself more employable.

I just started with RF because it was looking interesting but as I started to explore, I found very less jobs for RF.

How employable can RF make you in comparison to other open source automation frameworks like Cucumber, TestNG, Selenium, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a tool that makes you more employable, it's your experience. Knowledge of some tool *may* give you some advantage but only if you have other skills. No one looks for a guy who can click around in Robot Framework or Selenium or TestNG. A guy who knows how to test (whatever tool is used) - that guy gets the job.

Learning RF will not make you *less* employable of course, but i would invest my time in more fundamental things such as theory of testing software.

Comment: Great answer. I would also invest into learning programming. Lot's of candidates are rejected because they can use a library but can write a simple loop. Plus once you can program thrn switching testing libraries is so much easier.